# Clarifai API For video tagging

Tags: video

The api has a working jpg, but the help section says we can get tagging done for video. https://developer.clarifai.com/docs/tag. is there a way to get tagging done for video.

Answer (score 0):

Good news! Clarifai supports videos in addition to images. The video response is slightly different from the image one since it returns an analysis from each second with tags and corresponding timestamps, but otherwise it is what you'd expect. Simply put in a local video file or hosted URL with the same code in the API documentation.

Good luck!

Jared